# How to search something in ; Setinterval() "div" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, setinterval

I have a page with javascript setinterval and calling data from another page each 1000 ms..

But I couldnt figure "searching" out in same div.. How can I do that?

The problem is When I start to keyup for some words to search , page refreshing background...

```html
<input style="width:100%" class=" form-control-sm" 
       id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction();"
       type="text" placeholder="PROJELERDE ARA..">
    <div class="container" id="myTable1"> 
        <div id="myTable" >
    <div id="rev" >
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    $('#rev').load('yansima.php')
  }, 1000);
});
    
function myFunction() {
 var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("myTable");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("table1");
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
       txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
       if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         tr[i].style.display = "";
       } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
       }
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

```
.yansima.php  :
```

```html
<table1 id=""> 
  <table class="table table-borderless table-hover table-sm " style="border: 2px solid black;"> 
    <tr>
      ..................
    </tr>
  </table>
</table1>
```

Comment: just pass the event object inside the function and use event.preventDefault() ? Also, aren't you loading the page every second in your jQuery handler?

Comment: There must be a mistake in the string: tr = table.getElementsByTagName("table1");

Comment: I can use search without  setinterval the  problem I have is : refreshing page always break searching prrogress...

Comment: @rags2riches  please can you write down clearly what you mean?

Comment: @Jane, `myFunction(evt)` and then inside the function call `evt.preventDefault()`. You are saying that when keyup is triggered, the page reload...but your page should reload every second because of your jQuery handler

Comment: it didint work :S
function myFunction(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
 var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;